# How to use Generator Yield of multi paths&multi classes Unet

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I modified it from zhihuhao/unet

I concatenate 6 GLCM images to perform a UNet classification task.

But in training, system only read class1 image,mask and loss value is very big,how to reslove this problem.

Maybe I should append every concatenate_image then use zip(img,mask) to yield?

```
folders = [
    'classes1/glcm1', #7 classes, 42 paths
    'classes1/glcm2',
    'classes1/glcm3',
    'classes1/glcm4',
    'classes1/glcm5', 
    'classes1/glcm6',
    'classes2/glcm1',
        …
    'classes7/glcm6',
]
```

```
def Generator(...)

    for paths in folders:
        image_generator = a.flow_from_directory(...)
        mask_generator = b.flow_from_directory(...)
        
        img_append.append(image_generator) #append 6 glcm folders
        mask_append.append(mask_generator)
        count += 1
        if count %6 == 0:
            img_zip = zip(*img_append) #zip *glcm folders to concatenate
            mask_zip = zip(*mask_append)
            for six_img, six_mask in zip(img_zip,mask_zip):
                img_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_img, axis=3) 
                mask_concatenate = np.concatenate(six_mask, axis=3) 
                yield (img_concatenate,mask_concatenate)

                #img,mask = adjustData(img_concatenate,mask_concatenate,flag_multi_class,num_class)
                #yield (img,mask)
   
            img_append = []
            mask_append = []
```

by the way, convert mask to one-hot vector in classification task is nesscery?

I found adjustData function,but it seem will affect concatenate mask.